# Accessing Google Account ID/username via Android (pre-2.0)

Tags: android, identity, google-account

How do you access the user's Google Account ID/username in code (pre-2.0)? I am building an application that will call a web service to store data and I want to identify the identity of the person submitting the data.

If no user identity information is available pre-2.0, how about the ability to access phone identity (again, pre-2.0)?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing. But the only thing that I can think of is: Use the web service to create a unique ID. Pass that back to your app and store it in a small SQLlite db. So every time your application starts, it uses that ID to correspond with your Web Service.

Does not give you much information about the phone itself, but atleast you can associate the Web Service usage with something.